# Какие должны быть таблице в базе данных при создании одностраничного сайта?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Я думал разбить таблицы в базе данных по секциям ( header, content , footer)  или по определенным фрагментам( например , если несколько карточек товаров , то создать для них таблицу )  , как правильней создать структуру базы данных?

База данных нужна для того , чтобы изменять верстку

Comment: Для одностраничника можно вообще всё в html запихнуть и не мучаться с базами. Особенно, когда такие вопросы возникают

Comment: Изменить верстку можно и редактированием файла.

Comment: База данных не нужна чтобы изменить верстку

Comment: Можно по подробнее зачем ты хочешь > разбить таблицы в базе данных по секциям ( header, content , footer) Легче будет если ты скажешь что собираешься делать (опиши свою страницу).

Comment: У Вас вёрстка уже есть или Вы только собираетесь её делать?